# Текст из базы данных отображается некорректно

Tags: кодировка, веб-программирование

Добрый день! Имеется следующий сайт http://integral.besaba.com/index.php

Возникла проблема с кодировкой: текст из базы данных отображается некорректно. В чем может быть проблема? Кидайте предложения. Кодировка в базе данных стоит `utf8_general_ci`. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы, я надеюсь, правильно преобразовываете данные при чтении из базы данных/при выводе их на страницу? Вы знаете про каждую строку в вашем коде, в какой кодировке она? (А если нет, то почему?)

Comment: Ради интереса, попробуйте в одном из файлов с исходниками сделать кодировку utf-8 без BOM (например в notepad++). Сайт же на PHP?

Comment: VladD, не знаю про строковую переменную. Где это искать?

Comment: ghost rider, сайт на php. Верно.

Comment: ghost rider, не помогло. Такая же ерунда.

Comment: @IntegralAL: Вы не знаете, что такое "строковая переменная"? Эээ... А как же вы программируете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совсем не странно. Сайт отдается в кодировке `windows-1251`. Меню тоже в этой кодировке, т.к. отображается нормально. 
Данные из базы приходят в `utf-8` и отображаются коряво.

Выставьте кодировку страницы в `utf-8` и сохраните страницы сайта в той же кодировке, либо преобразовывайте полученное из БД в `windows-1251`.

Для PHP инфа тут: [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

Comment: Выставлять кодировку страницы в зависимости от кодировки базы некошерно: не дело базы определять, в какой кодировке я отправляю документ. А вот преобразовать данные из БД в нужную кодировку после чтения — правильная мысль.

Comment: спасибо, буду двигаться в этом направлении...

Comment: вопрос такой, почему на денвере (на локальной машине) все корректно отражалось, а тут так коряво?

Comment: @VladD, согласен. Первый вариант написан на случай для людей, которые думают, что выставив кодировку базы в ``UTF-8`` они получат сайт в ``UTF-8``. 

@IntegralAL, это уже не важно. Как-то работало - может у вас там файлы были в другой кодировке, может сервер отдавал другую кодировку, может база была в другой кодировке. Может..

Comment: ну спасибо, я сделал все... можете полюбоваться)) на сайт.

Comment: поздравляю :)